# Server error in logout: contentPath null or empty

Tags: c#, session, path, server, logout

I made a web with authentication. When I press the logout button the following error shows, but the logout is correct. I mean, if you reload the page the login form appears and works fine.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: contentPath
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: contentPath

Source Error:
[No relevant source lines]

Source File: c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\f60d396e\617997\App_Web_hs3arjh1.3.cs    Line: 0 

Stack Trace:
[ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: contentPath]
   System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(String contentPath, HttpContextBase httpContext) +130
   System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Content(String contentPath) +42
   ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\Manuel\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\f60d396e\617997\App_Web_hs3arjh1.3.cs:0
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +177
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +80
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +113
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer) +26
   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass3.<RenderPageCore>b__2(TextWriter writer) +210
   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +27
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.WriteTo(TextWriter writer, HelperResult content) +31
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +32
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +101
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +146
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +120
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +297
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +248
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +58
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +349
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +69
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +188
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +124
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +24
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +23
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9742689
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

This is the code to make the logout.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Logout()
{
    System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session.Clear();
    Session.RemoveAll();

    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
}
```

I tried to make the logout without the *session* lines but it keeps the session.

Comment: on your view, do you have a reference to something like `@Url.Content` ?

Comment: Yes, a lot. I use them to load the assets and the .js

Comment: ok, so do you have one that is empty? like `@Url.Content("")`? that would cause the error you are experiencing.

Comment: No, all of them are with reference. I'm check all of them and seems ok. Is there any way to try them to see if they are ok?

Comment: Im been doing test and the page trows the error when it tries to render anything. It is posible that the application loses the content path?